# How to get eslint score similar to pylint score?

Tags: continuous-integration, eslint, lint, badge

I already created a badge to show my **pylint** score:

[image]

Now I would like to do something similar with **eslint** for my frontend.
However, eslint does not seem to calculate a score value by default.

=> How can I print an eslint score or calculate a value that works similar to the pylint score?