# How to change label for GitHub workflow status badge?

Tags: github, workflow, badge

I have a workflow status badge

```
[![front_end_lint](https://github.com/fraunhofer-isi/micat/actions/workflows/front_end_lint.yml/badge.svg)](https://github.com/fraunhofer-isi/micat/actions/workflows/front_end_lint.yml)
```

and use it at https://github.com/fraunhofer-isi/micatf

How can **change the svg label** "front_end_lint" to "lint" without changing the name of the worfklow action file?

I tried to append a `label` query argument to the url but that did not work:

```
https://github.com/fraunhofer-isi/micat/actions/workflows/front_end_lint.yml/badge.svg?label="lint"
```

[image]

**Related:**

Workflows in sub directories: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/18055

Eslint score: [How to get eslint score similar to pylint score?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76804537/how-to-get-eslint-score-similar-to-pylint-score)

Answer (score 0):

The markdown for your badge doesn't change. Instead, add `name: Lint` to your workflow file.